# jboss 7.0.1 hibernate javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, jboss7.x

My hibernate app was running successfully in jboss-as-7.0.0.Final, I moved it to jboss-as-7.0.1.Final and I started receiving these errors

```
17:42:42,725 ERROR [com.mycompany.myapp.common.persistence.HibernateUtil] (MSC service thread 1-12) Initial SessionFactory lookup failed.: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named primary2
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69) [hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:1.0.1.Final]
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47) [hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:1.0.1.Final]
at com.mycompany.myapp.common.persistence.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:35) [classes:]
at com.mycompany.myapp.common.businessobjects.ServerSettings.GetServerSettings(ServerSettings.java:84) [classes:]
at com.mycompany.myapp.common.jms.JMSListenerServletTemplate.init(JMSListenerServletTemplate.java:41) [classes:]
at com.mycompany.myapp.common.jms.JMSAnywhereServlet.init(JMSAnywhereServlet.java:179) [classes:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3631) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3844) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_26]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_26]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [:1.6.0_26]

17:42:42,732 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myapp]] (MSC service thread 1-12) StandardWrapper.Throwable: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mycompany.myapp.common.persistence.HibernateUtil
at com.mycompany.myapp.common.businessobjects.ServerSettings.GetServerSettings(ServerSettings.java:92) [classes:]
at com.mycompany.myapp.common.jms.JMSListenerServletTemplate.init(JMSListenerServletTemplate.java:41) [classes:]
at com.mycompany.myapp.common.jms.JMSAnywhereServlet.init(JMSAnywhereServlet.java:179) [classes:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3631) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3844) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_26]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_26]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [:1.6.0_26]

17:42:42,734 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myapp]] (MSC service thread 1-12) Servlet /myapp threw load() exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mycompany.myapp.common.persistence.HibernateUtil
at com.mycompany.myapp.common.businessobjects.ServerSettings.GetServerSettings(ServerSettings.java:92) [classes:]
at com.mycompany.myapp.common.jms.JMSListenerServletTemplate.init(JMSListenerServletTemplate.java:41) [classes:]
at com.mycompany.myapp.common.jms.JMSAnywhereServlet.init(JMSAnywhereServlet.java:179) [classes:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3631) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3844) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_26]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_26]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [:1.6.0_26]
```

my persistence.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
  <non-jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS</non-jta-data-source>

  <properties>

     <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
     <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor.session_scoped" value="com.clairvista.liveexpert.common.persistence.BusinessObjectInterceptor"/>
           </properties>
```

and my pom.xml looks like

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.Beta5</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.Beta5</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-infinispan</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.Beta5</version>
  </dependency>
```

the code that throws these errors looks like

```
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("primary");
```

I'm not sure what's going on - this app was working in jboss-as-7.0.0.Final.  I know 7.0.1 has better support for hibernate versions bundled within applications - but I'm not sure how this relates to my problem as I'd like to use the version of hibernate that comes bundled with the container.  Any ideas?

Comment: Check the tree context of the server, see if factory had well deployed

Comment: How can I check the tree context?

Comment: i'm not sure how this could change in the version 7.0 i know how to do it in version 4.5, after you had deployed your server, access to the web console in the path for example http://localhost:8280 then click to the jmx-console, look for `jndi view` and invoke the `listXML` service and you will see al the jdni names, and find which are missing

Comment: Apparently this is a bug with 7.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have any of the `hibernate-` dependencies in our `pom.xml` since JBoss already has them. You just need the JBoss 7 libraries which are set to *provided*.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The `NoClassDefFoundError` usually relates to a class or interface being twice in the classpath, so the class loader does not know, which one to use.

Comment: [ERROR] /Users/me/Documents/hg/myapp-maven/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/common/businessobjects/Product.java:[18,25] package org.hibernate.type does not exist

Comment: I included the JBoss 7 libraries as you suggested, and I commented out the hibernate dependencies in my pom.xml.  I get many of these types of errors during maven build.

Answer (score 0):

The error says "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named primary2"

but your persistence.xml names the unit "primary" (without the suffix 2):

```
<persistence-unit name="primary">
```

Can this be the issue?

Comment: That was a typo on my part, the name of the PU is correct but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: So how is the error with your previous pom.xml but *with* the corrected data source name?

Answer (score 0):

You should set all the `<scope>`s of your hibernate dependencies to `provided` as it is included in JBoss 7.

For example, with your first dependency, you should write :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.Beta5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```